# YapDataBase Warnings: Umbrella header for module 'YapDatabase' does not include header

Tags: objective-c, warnings, yapdatabase

YapDatabase installed via CocoaPods and included using module style
`@import YapDatabase;` It works good, but I get a bunch of strange warnings. [image]

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'pod update' in your terminal. That fixed this same problem for me.